# Determine how long a customer has been in a database table

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have a customer table and the only column I have to work with is the date column. The customer's record is inserted into this table and only removed from it upon a certain action. I am trying to figure out a query that would show me exactly how long said customer has been in this table using only a date field.

Comment: If it isn't a datetime field, I don't think there's much you can do. Is it impossible to add a time field, and set DEFAULT as now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will tell you how many days each record has been passed since the date indicated in your `DateField`:

```
select dateDiff(day, DateField, GetDate()) from YourTable
```

For more information, read more about [`DateFiff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)